# pass parameter from jsp to another jsp dynamically

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, jstl

i am working on java application where user's login and predict football matches , i create an admin jsp to get all teams name from stored table in database to set this week matches and set the final results later when the matches finish to compare them with users results and calculate points , top users etc ...

my admin.jsp where i choose matches team from jstl foreach loop and set the final result later to compare them with user prediction results.

```
<%@page import="pws.daoImp.UsersDaoImp"%>
<%@page import="java.lang.String"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page import="pws.beans.Users"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>

<%       request.getAttribute("admminresult");
%>

<%
    List<String> teams1 = new ArrayList();


    UsersDaoImp udi = new UsersDaoImp();
    List<String> admminresult = new ArrayList();
    admminresult = udi.getadminresult();
    request.setAttribute("admminresult", admminresult);
    List<String> teams = new ArrayList();
    teams = udi.getallteams();
    request.setAttribute("teams", teams);



%>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Match Prediction</title>


</head>
<body>





<div>
    <h1 class="title">Welcome to Match Prediction Site </h1>
    <div id="logo" >
        <img src="images/cl.png" alt="Smiley face" width="142" height="142">
    </div>
</div>
<form action ="AdminUserHandling" method = "post" >

    <div class="form-lables">
        <h1><select name="clteam1" >
                <c:forEach items="${teams}"  var="teams"  >
                    <option name="clm1g1" value="${teams}">
                        ${teams}
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> Vs <select name="clteam1" >
                <c:forEach items="${teams}"  var="teams"  >
                    <option name="clm1g1" value="${teams}">
                        ${teams}
                    </option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select> </h1>
        <label for="user_lic">Goals : </label><input id="user_lic" name="clm1g1" type="number" min="" max="10" step="1" value ="1"/>
        <label for="user_lic">Goals : </label><input id="user_lic" name="clm1g2" type="number" min="" max="10" step="1" value ="1"/>
    </div>


    <input type ="submit" value="Submit" />

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and my servlet code

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {


     UsersDaoImp udi = new UsersDaoImp();


    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String team1 = request.getParameter("clteam1");
    String team2 = request.getParameter("clteam2");
    String team1gl = request.getParameter("clteam1gl");
    String team2gl = request.getParameter("clteam2gl");
     Users user = (Users) request.getSession().getAttribute("user");



    System.out.println(team1);

    System.out.println(team2);

     udi.adminhandling(team1, team2,team1gl,team2gl); //save teams name and goals in database

    processRequest(request, response);
}


}
```

my question is that i set the teams name and final result in admin page jsp but have problem to pass them to users jsp dynamically , iam running out of ideas to do so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[RequestDispatcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html)**.

> Defines an object that receives requests from the client and sends
>   them to any resource (such as a servlet, HTML file, or JSP file) on
>   the server. The servlet container creates the RequestDispatcher
>   object, which is used as a wrapper around a server resource located at
>   a particular path or given by a particular name.

```
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/to/your/users.jsp"); // mention correct path to your user.jsp here
request.setAttribute("teams",teams);
rd.forward(request, response);
```

**Or**

You can set the object into **Session**.

```
 HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
 session.setAttribute("teams",teams);
```